# I think I may have wasted some money. Can a docking station work with a USB switcher?

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, docking-station

I have a desktop for home use and a laptop for work.

I want them to share monitors/peripherals (keyboard/mouse/headset).

So, I had an [old HP G2 Thunderbolt lying around.](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-thunderbolt-dock-g2-with-combo-cable). For monitors, it works fine. the desktop is hooked directly into monitors with HDMI, and the Thunderbolt is hooked into them with VGA, and it switches automatically when plugged in. Here's where I did a stupid though.

[I ordered a USB switcher - link.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01N6GD9JO/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). It works fine for the desktop since it is directly hooked in. For the laptop, it does not, since my intention was to hook it in via the Thunderbolt G2 docking station.

This won't work though, will it? It needs to install drivers and stuff? It certainly doesn't seem to. The lights on 2/3 of the devices I wanted to use don't even come on.

Anything I can do at this point or am I just hosed?

Thanks, I will set bounty on this and award it to any answer that saves me!

Comment: Your dock is incompatible with your USB 3.0 switch

Comment: @Ramhound how do you know? What is a compatible option?

Comment: USB 3.0 doesn’t support Thunderbolt, that requires I believe USB 3.0 Gen 1, I assume by “it” you are referring to the dock itself when connected to the USB 3.0 switch?

Comment: The switcher supports USB3.0 Gen 1.

Comment: USB is a screwed up standard I was thinking of USB 3.2 Gen 2; My apologizes